# what is the relation between the number of elements in a geometric sequence and its summation?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the following sequence:

$1 + 3 + 9 + 27 + 81 + ... 3^{n-1} = S$

I know that the summation formula is:

$S = \frac{1-3^{n}}{1-3}$

Now, what is the relation between $n$ and $S$?

I guess it's a logarithmic relation, however, I would like to know is there a straight formula for any geometric sequence?

Answer (score 3):

For $x \ne 1$ we have

$S=1+x+x^2+...+x^{n-1}= \frac{x^n-1}{x-1}$, hence $x^n=S(x-1)+1$.

Can you proceed ?

Comment: thanks, you mean $n = log( S(x-1)) +1)$ in the base of $x$

Answer (score 1):

As you know,
$$S=  \frac {r^n - 1}{r-1} $$ **where r $ \neq $ 1**

So, $$S(r-1)= r^n-1  $$
Or, $$r^n=1+S(r-1)  $$
Taking log on both sides:
$$n \cdot log(r)=log(1+S(r-1))  $$
So, $$n= \frac{log(1+S(r-1))}{logr}$$